# Keeping primroses compact when dividing

Tags: propagation

Primroses form a beautiful rosette with flowers in the middle, but over time, with regular pruning, they become cluttered with pruned-out stumps and need dividing.

Somehow my divided primroses never get that pretty rosette aesthetic that you find when they're shop-bought. Flowers tend to grow from one side or the other rather than in the middle.

How can I give my primroses the best aesthetic when dividing?

Living in South Coast UK near Portsmouth.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because you are, for some reason, cutting/pruning them, which is not normally done. Leave them alone to do their thing and twin up or form new offset plants, then dig up a clump and split them into their individual plants and replant. If your soil is heavy, it's often easier to separate clumps into individual plants by soaking the roots and teasing out the ones belonging to each.